# to pass button name to variable in function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

I want to pass button name to a part of variable.but did not get success.please help me.thank you.

```
[Embed(source="desenler/k1r1.jpg", mimeType="image/jpeg")]
      public var Imgk1r1:Class;
[Embed(source="desenler/k1r2.jpg", mimeType="image/jpeg")]
      public var Imgk1r2:Class; 


k1r1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onbi);
k1r2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onbi);

    private function onbi(e:MouseEvent):void {

        bdWindow=new  Imgk1r1().bitmapData;
```

*instead of that, I want to pass button name*

```
bdWindow=new Img+button name+().bitmapData;
```

*I tried that*

```
 bdWindow=new  ["Img"+e.currentTarget.name+"().bitmapData"];
```

but it says "Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. 
Since Imgk1r1 is a variable of `this` (whatever that may be in your case), you should be able to access it with the bracket notation as follows:

```
private function onbi(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    bdWindow = Bitmap(new this["Img"+DisplayObject(e.currentTarget).name]()).bitmapData;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcela,thank you for your interest but it says;                ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Imgk1r1 is not defined.
 at global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName()

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot that you were embedding the images, not exporting them for ActionScript. The edited code sample should work.